# Rails Routing error in production - debian and passenger (not static asset issue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, passenger, production-environment

I've been developing a RoR app for nearly 8 months and it's finally ready to deploy. It's running on a Debian server with Passenger.

I was able to run the migration to setup my database schema, but now when the app starts (automatically in production with Passenger) it immediately takes me to my 500.html error page in the public folder.

In my production.log I see this:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/tms/public/external/management/systemmanagementservice.asmx"):`

I've already set `config.serve_static_assets = true` in my environments/production.rb file.

I cant find ANYTHING about this online.  Did I miss a step? I've been messing with this for HOURS and getting really discouraged. I'm tempted to run my app in development mode on the :3000 address, as it works perfectly there!

Full Error log:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/tms/public/external/management/systemmanagementservice.asmx"):
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:516:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:470:in `safe_fork'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
passenger (3.0.19) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
passenger (3.0.19) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

Any help extremely appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean. Where do I find this?

Comment: The complete error log posted above. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: A error trace include a backtrace of error, showing what files program was running when error occurred. It's in your file log (or should be). Look at: http://www.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=872

Comment: @daniloisr isn't that what I posted above?

Comment: Are you using any external service, like SOAP, etc.? If you are, make sure they are running.

Comment: @daniloisr I'm not that I'm aware of. I only installed Passenger.

Comment: Have you tried to access the file  `/tms/public/external/management/systemmanagementservice.asmx` direct?  I think that by some way Passenger is not recognizing this file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35157/discussion-between-daniloisr-and-devin)

Comment: @daniloisr File doesn't exist. I've looked through all my folders, as well as tried to visit the direct URL. not found. :(

Comment: what's the result of `grep -rin systemmanagementservice YOUR_RAILS_APP` ?

Comment: I believe I resolved the main issue with this... I deleted the contents of the /tmp folder in my app, then restarted and now the root route loads!  Only now, not all my routes are working. But this is probably a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting in the contents of the /tmp folder in my rails app and then restarting Debian resolved this issue.